# Rounding in Scala and division

Tags: scala

I have some Scala division code like this:

```
order.price.toBigDecimal.round(MathContext.DECIMAL128) / order.subPrice.toBigDecimal).toString
```

That does not work. It throws me this error:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
```

I wrote this in return, but it does not round. It gives me a number like this: `9.8431984893148934`

```
order.price.toBigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble / order.subPrice.toBigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
```

What can I do if the number I want returned from this division to have only two decimal places?

Comment: what are the actual values of price and collar price?

Comment: What does "has only two decimal places" mean? Which number are you referring to?

Comment: the return value I want to look like `94.39`

Answer (score 4):

Your expression

```
order.price.toBigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble / order.subPrice.toBigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
```

is basically a division of a `Double` by a `Double`, which gives back a `Double` with the exact result. I think what you're after might be

```
(order.price / order.subPrice).toBigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
```

which produces a number with 2 decimal places. Notice we round the result of the division and not the operands, so as not to lose precision.